# how to validate view visibility on button click listener

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, visibility, invisible

I am using this code for validation and only invisibility view is working .

```
mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mute = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mute);
        if (mute.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE) {
            power.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            power.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Whether you know about `View.VISIBLE` something is there in android?

Comment: GONE and INVISIBLE are both means invisible in some sort, you meant VISIBLE I guess

Comment: Why are you checking the visibility of `mute`?  It's visibility probably remains the same, so you will not change anything in your onClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this it works..... create boolean variable as global within class but outside methods.

```
 boolean flag=true;
```

and add this clicked method.

```
  @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


if (flag){
            power.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            flag=false;
        }
        else {
            flag=true;
           power.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

    }


        });
```

mute always visible , because you performing visibility with power that why the result coming same.

enjoy coding....

Comment: I  checked as like that but its performing only invisibility but i want both on same button click is it require another conditional statement?

Comment: check your xml also. make sure visibility true for the first time .

Comment: @Arman please have look on edit answer it is running. I checked it .

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didnt change is `View.GONE` and `View.INVISIBLE` has the  same behavior which is to hide the element. To show the element, you should use `View.VISIBLE` .

Another tip: make the mute variable a global variable and use isShown method. Always remember, initialize your variable on `onCreate` method as initializing it on `onClick`, there is a difference on its performance.

```
Imageview mute;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mute = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mute);
    mute.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mute.isShown())
        power.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else
        power.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`View.INVISIBLE` and `View.GONE` have the same effect and your view won't be visible.

The only diference is that using `INVISIBLE` the view will still takes up space for layout purposes, and using `GONE` the view will take any space.

You should use `View.VISIBLE`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    mute = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mute);
    if (mute.isShown())
        power.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        power.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
if (mute.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE)
       power.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
else
       power.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is simple solution hope this will help you.

```
if (yoursecondLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

        yourfirstlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        yoursecondLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        yourfirstlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yoursecondLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```